# pthread_cond_wait strange behaviour

Tags: c++, pthreads, dining-philosopher

I'm trying to solve [Dining philosophers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) using C++.

Code is compiled with `g++ -lpthread`.

Entire solution is on [philosophers github](https://github.com/akegalj/cplusplus/tree/master/rltest/dining_philosophers). Repository contains two cpp files: main.cpp and philosopher.cpp. "Main.cpp" creates mutex variable, semaphore, 5 conditinal variables, 5 forks, and starts philosophers. Semaphore is used only to synchronize start of philosophers. Other parameters are passed to philosophers to solve a problem. "Philosopher.cpp" contains solution for given problem but after few steps deadlock occurs.

Deadlock occurs when philosopher 0 is eating, and philosopher 1 (next to him) wants to take forks. Then, philosopher 1 has taken mutex, and wont give it back until philosopher 0 puts his forks down. Philosopher 0 can't put his forks down because of taken mutex, so we have a deadlock. Problem is in **Philosopher::take_fork method, call for pthread_cond_wait(a,b) isn't releasing mutex b**. Can't figure out why?

```
// Taking fork. If eather lef or right fork is taken, wait.
void Philosopher::take_fork(){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mon);
  std::cout << "Philosopher " << id << " is waiting on forks" << std::endl;
  while(!fork[id] || !fork[(id + 1)%N])
    pthread_cond_wait(cond + id, &mon);
  fork[id] = fork[(id + 1)%N] = false;
  std::cout << "Philosopher " << id << " is eating" << std::endl;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mon);
}
```

Please reference to [this code](https://github.com/akegalj/cplusplus/tree/master/rltest/dining_philosophers) for the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `pthread_cond_wait()` is fine, so the problem must be elsewhere.  You have three bugs that I can see:

Firstly, in `main()` you are only initialising the *first* condition variable in the array.  You need to initialise all `N` condition variables:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    fork[i] = true;
    pthread_cond_init(&cond[i], NULL);
}

pthread_mutex_init(&mon, NULL);
```

Secondly, in `put_fork()` you have an incorrect calculation for one of the condition variables to signal:

```
pthread_cond_signal(cond + (id-1)%N);    /* incorrect */
```

When `id` is equal to zero, `(id - 1) % N` is equal to -1, so this will try to signal `cond - 1`, which does not point at a condition variable (it's possible that this pointer actually corrupts your mutex, since it might well be placed directly before `cond` on the stack).  The calculation you actually want is:

```
pthread_cond_signal(cond + (id + N - 1) % N);
```

The third bug isn't the cause of your deadlock, but you shouldn't call `srand(time(NULL))` every time you call `rand()` - just call that once, at the start of `main()`.

Comment: Thank you. Problem was in not initialising all conditional variables.